# Routing error in tutorial app converted from rails 2.x to 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I'am working on sixrevision.com tutorial “How to Create a Blog from Scratch Using Ruby on Rails” . I try to convert It from rails 2.x to 3.x. When I run localhost:3000 I get this:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant PostController

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Rake Routes shows me this:

```
    posts GET  /posts(.:format)               posts#index {:has_many=>:comments}
          POST /posts(.:format)               posts#create {:has_many=>:comments}
 new_post GET  /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new {:has_many=>:comments}
edit_post GET  /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit {:has_many=>:comments}
     post GET  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show {:has_many=>:comments}
          PUT  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update {:has_many=>:comments}
       DELETE  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy {:has_many=>:comments}
               /:controller/:action/:id(.:format) :controller#:action
               /:controller/:action/:id.:format   :controller#:action
   root        /                                  post#index
```

My routes.rb file:

```
    Myblog::Application.routes.draw do

       resources :posts, :has_many => :comments
       match ':controller/:action/:id'
       match ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
       root :to => "post#index"

    end
```

Anybody got any idea? Thanks for intrest & help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.rb you should have:

```
root :to => 'posts#index'
```

because you do not have (probably) PostController but PostsController